# Bash string how to remove characters after colon but before ampersand

Tags: bash

Not sure how to slice this string to remove just the characters after the colon but include the stuff after the ampersand

```
image="eclipse-temurin:254324@SHA256=f1bb9b6ed77176166"
```

Expected outcome should be `image=eclipse-temurin@SHA256=f1bb9b6ed77176166`

Comment: There's no ampersand (`&`). You mean at-sign `@`.

Comment: And what about the double quotes?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet The double quotes aren't in the string, that's just shell syntax when assigning variables.

Comment: @Barmar Well, the shown expected outcome seems to indicate that it is the whole assignment that must be modified, not just the assigned value...

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Maybe, but it could just be poor wording and he means that the expected result is that the variable is equal to that. That's how I interpreted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume by 'ampersand' (`&`), you mean 'at' (`@`). If so, Try:

```
image="eclipse-temurin:254324@SHA256=f1bb9b6ed77176166"
echo ${image/:*@/@}
```

Comment: The pattern is a globbing pattern, not regular expression. So it should just be `:*@`, no `.`

Comment: Thanks. I fixed it. My erroneous pattern worked in testing because `.*` is still valid (one character followed by any number of characters).

Comment: `.*` only matches the specific character `.` in a glob/fnmatch pattern, not _any_ one character as it does in regex. The "any one character" in glob/fnmatch is `?`

Comment: So it does. Silly me.